# Best practices for OAuth + REST API logging? What should an OAuth access logging statistics table look like?

Tags: sql, rest, logging, oauth, rdbms

What are the best practices for logging an OAuth REST API? I would like to keep the database to a minimum as the http logs can store a lot. However, I also want to monitor usage and instantly detect abuse.

Is there a custom [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) for Apache can be set to keep much of the data?

If I was to make a table that logged usage of a REST API that used an OAuth security mechanism, what should that table look like? I am new to OAuth and want to make sure I don't overlook things.

Here is what I have so far...

```
"access_log"
access_method VARCHAR(8) -- PUT/GET/POST/DELETE/etc..
request_uri VARCHAR(1024)
token_id int references token.id
user_id int references user.id
```

As a common starting point, let's assume the tables look like those listed in this [OAuth Provider example](http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/).

```
"user"
id  int , auto_increment
login   varchar(50)

"consumer"
id  int , auto_increment
consumer_key    varchar(250)
consumer_secret varchar(250)
active  tinyint(1)

"consumer_nonce"
id  int , auto_increment
consumer_id int references consumer.id
timestamp   bigint
nonce   varchar(250)

"token"
id  int , auto_increment
user_id int references user.id
type    int references token_type.id
consumer_id int references consumer.id
token   varchar(250)
token_secret    varchar(250)
callback_url    varchar(250)
verifier    varchar(250)

"token_type" // 1 = Request, 2 = Access
id  int , auto_increment
type    varchar(50)
```

Comment: I think your token table should reference user.id.

Comment: Thanks for looking Diego. Yes, I agree and added the column. My tables are slightly different, however these are a public working example, so I figured it would be a better model.

Comment: I wrote my OAuth provider with oauth-php. Do use that, or learn from those tables.